# Connection not allowed to Mysql server via IISExpress

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, iis-express

When connecting to the mysql server on my localhost via an iisexpress server I get the following error:

> iisexpress.exe Error: 0 : Host 'MyPcName' is not allowed to connect to
>   this MySQL server

But the problem is it only happens to certain connections and there is no real difference between the connection or/and task.

Is this a problem of mysql or of iisexpress? And how do I know what it is and fix it?

I'm using MySQL Connector Net 6.7.4 ,Visual Studio 2013 and XAMPP 1.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html):

> f the following error occurs when you try to connect from a host other
>   than the one on which the MySQL server is running, it means that there
>   is no row in the user table with a Host value that matches the client
>   host:
>
> **Host ... is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server**
>
> You can fix this by setting up an account for the combination of
>   client host name and user name that you are using when trying to
>   connect.
>
> If you do not know the IP address or host name of the machine from
>   which you are connecting, you should put a row with '%' as the Host
>   column value in the user table. After trying to connect from the
>   client machine, use a SELECT USER() query to see how you really did
>   connect. Then change the '%' in the user table row to the actual host
>   name that shows up in the log. Otherwise, your system is left insecure
>   because it permits connections from any host for the given user name.

Comment: It has the same connection string as the other connections but those won't be dis-allowed.